# Is it optimal to use "OR" for multiple sub-queries?

Tags: mysql

I have a slow query of the following form.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table e
WHERE e.eid in (select eid from view1)
OR e.eid in (select eid from view1)
OR e.eid in (select eid from view2)
OR e.eid in (select eid from view3)
OR e.eid in (select eid from view4)
OR e.eid in (select eid from view5)
```

I am new to MySQL but is there a faster way to make this query?

Comment: The problem here is almost certainly the use of views rather than accessing the source tables directly. Performance then is limited by the complexity of the views, and the precise manner in which they have been created.

Answer (score 1):

May be using `UNION` like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table e
WHERE e.eid IN
(
    SELECT eid FROM view1
    UNION
    SELECT eid FROM view2
    UNION
    SELECT eid FROM view3
    UNION
    SELECT eid FROM view4
    UNION
    SELECT eid FROM view5
)
```

Comment: No joy :( it actually took longer; 204s versus 200s.

Comment: For some reason, the answer garnered more up-votes than the other answer. For future reference to other stack overflow users, the inner join method is ~10 more efficient than the in method.

Comment: @DavidBailey - FYI: I was editing my answer to add another query using `JOIN` but between that another answer{s) was/were added. So I revoked my edit.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Union in your query .

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.* 
FROM table e
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT eid FROM view1
UNION ALL
SELECT eid FROM view2
UNION ALL
SELECT eid FROM view3
UNION ALL
SELECT eid FROM view4
UNION ALL
SELECT eid FROM view5
) AS B ON e.eid = B.eid
```

you should use join query instead of using IN query . IN query will run for each rows of the table so it will take more time . Join query will run only one time .

Comment: is this query helpful to you ?

Comment: Wow! The winner so far; from 200s to 24s. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Using `id IN (unioned subquery)` generally won't perform well.

Try using a standard join on a unioned subquery:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (
  SELECT eid FROM view1
  UNION
  SELECT eid FROM view2
  UNION
  SELECT eid FROM view3
  UNION
  SELECT eid FROM view4
  UNION
  SELECT eid FROM view5
) e
JOIN table a ON a.id = e.eid
```

The important thing here is that the ids from the views come *first* in the FROM table list, so that table can be accessed efficiently, not the other way around when the in indexed view result would have to be table-scanned for every row of table.

Also note there is no need for DISTINCT because the UNION inside the subquery eliminated duplicates.

This query should perform very well.